# Why was film's setting changed from Mars to Earth in the remake?

Tags: total-recall, total-recall-2012

In the first movie (1990), Douglas Quaid dreams of Mars and a big part of the story takes place on Mars. Even the Philip K Dick story *We Can Remember It for You Wholesale* is based on Mars. But in 2012 remake there is no Mars.

Was there a reason that the setting was changed from Mars to Earth?

Comment: If this is about the integrity of adaptations, the general answer is Hollywood usually screws them up. Not *always*, but usually. I'm a PKD fan and would recommend Barjo http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104003/ to see a foreign interpretation of one of Dick's "mainstream" novels.

Comment: Quail (his name in the book) never goes to Mars in the original story, so it makes a lot more sense to never go there in the new version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Hollywood.

There's an [interview with the director](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1683538/total-recall-len-wiseman.jhtml) available which discusses this; the relevant excerpt is:

> **MTV**: Will we see Mars?
>
> **Wiseman**: We won't see Mars. And I got to say, it's one of the things that attracted me to the script, because I really, I along with a lot of other people, I really loved the Verhoeven film. I was very skeptical on just the reboot, just the idea. And until I read the script, with a lot of speculation going, it takes it in such a different direction from that film. Because it didn't go to Mars, funny enough, is why I was interested. And it's also just like I said: It plays a little bit into the threat of what the Philip K. Dick story had of, much more of bringing the threat back, really Doug's mission to save Earth, not Mars.